# Efficiency in Haskell when counting primes

Tags: performance, haskell, primes

I have the following set of functions to count the number of primes less than or equal to a number n in Haskell.

The algorithm takes a number, checks if it is divisible by two and then checks if it divisible by odd numbers up to the square root of the number being checked.

```
-- is a numner, n, prime? 
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = n > 1 &&
              foldr (\d r -> d * d > n || (n `rem` d /= 0 && r))
                True divisors

-- list of divisors for which to test primality
divisors :: [Int]
divisors = 2:[3,5..]

-- pi(n) - the prime counting function, the number of prime numbers <= n
primesNo :: Int -> Int
primesNo 2 = 1
primesNo n
    | isPrime n = 1 + primesNo (n-1)
    | otherwise = 0 + primesNo (n-1)

main = print $ primesNo (2^22)
```

Using GHC with the -O2 optimisation flag, counting the number of primes for n = 2^22 takes ~3.8sec on my system. The following C code take ~ 0.8 sec:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
    compile with: gcc -std=c11 -lm -O2 c_primes.c -o c_orig
*/

int isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 2)
        return 1;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return 0;
    int uL = sqrt(n);
    int i = 3;
    while (i <= uL) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;
        i+=2;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int noPrimes = 0, limit = 4194304;
    for (int n = 0; n <= limit; n++) {
        if (isPrime(n))
            noPrimes++;
    }
    printf("Number of primes in the interval [0,%d]: %d\n", limit, noPrimes);
    return 0;
}
```

This algorithm take about 0.9 sec in Java and 1.8 sec in JavaScript (on Node) so it just feels that the Haskell version is slower than I would expect be. Is there anyway I can more efficiently code this in Haskell without changing the algorithm?

---

### **EDIT**

The following version of isPrime offered by @dfeuer shaves one second off the running time taking it down to 2.8sec (down from 3.8). Though this is still slower than JavaScript (Node) which takes approx 1.8 sec as shown here, [Yet Another Language Speed Test](https://bjpelc.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/yet-another-language-speed-test-counting-primes-c-c-java-javascript-php-python-and-ruby-2/).

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
  | n <= 2 = n == 2
  | otherwise = odd n && go 3
  where
    go factor
      | factor * factor > n = True
      | otherwise = n `rem` factor /= 0 && go (factor+2)
```

---

### **EDIT**

In the above *isPrime* function, the function *go* calls *factor* * *factor* for each divisor for a single n. I would imagine that it would be more efficient to compare *factor* to the square root of *n* as this would only have to be calculated once per *n*. However, using the following code, computation time is increased by approximately 10%, is the square root of *n* being re-calculated every time the inequality is evaluated (for each *factor*)?

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
  | n <= 2 = n == 2
  | otherwise = odd n && go 3
  where
    go factor
      | factor > upperLim = True
      | otherwise = n `rem` factor /= 0 && go (factor+2)
      where
        upperLim = (floor.sqrt.fromIntegral) n
```

Comment: There are ways of improving your Haskell code. Could you specify exactly what you mean by *without changing the algorithm*, though?

Comment: Sure, by "without changing the algorithm", I mean the underlying algorithm, not how it is implemented. For example, by changing the algorithm, the code be made more efficient if the divisibility of a number was only checked against prime numbers and not all odd numbers. In other words, I still want the code to check against all odd numbers up to the square root of the number being checked. I suppose I am asking the equivalent of 'would it be quicker to use a for loop or a while loop' in C.

Comment: As to the question regarding `isPrime` with `sqrt`, `uppareLim` is definitely not recomputed for each factor. It's a basic optimization to float the definition one level higher. In fact, for me it's faster with `sqrt` when not using LLVM (and about the same with it). Don't know why you get the slowdown, maybe try benchmarking some more?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on then, I have just timed the version with the `factor > upperLim` ten times and get an average runtime of 3.01 seconds. Ten runs of the version with `factor * factor > n` gives me an average of 2.62 sec. I am using GHC 7.8.4 and am only compiling with the -O2 flag, I do not use LLVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I urge you to use a different algorithm, such as the Sieve of Eratosthenes discussed in the [paper](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) by Melissa O'Neill, or the version used in `Math.NumberTheory.Primes` from the [arithmoi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) package, which also offers an optimized prime counting function. However, this might get you better constant factors:

```
-- is a number, n, prime? 
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
  | n <= 2 = n == 2
  | otherwise = odd n && -- Put the 2 here instead
        foldr (\d r -> d * d > n || (n `rem` d /= 0 && r))
                True divisors

-- list of divisors for which to test primality
divisors :: [Int]
{-# INLINE divisors #-} -- No guarantee, but it might possibly inline and stay inlined,
               -- so the numbers will be generated on each call instead of
               -- being pulled in (expensively) from RAM.
divisors = [3,5..] -- No more 2:
```

The reason to get rid of the `2:` is that an optimization called "foldr/build fusion", "short cut deforestation", or just "list fusion" can, potentially, make your divisors list go away, but, at least with GHC < 7.10.1, that `2:` will block the optimization.

---

Edit: it seems that's not working for you, so here's something else to try:

```
isPrime n
  | n <= 2 = n == 2
  | otherwise = odd n && go 3
  where
    go factor
      | factor * factor > n = True
      | otherwise = n `rem` factor /= 0 && go (factor+2)
```

Comment: Interesting. I would further move the `odd` test outside the `foldr`, since there's no need to perform it at every iteration.

Comment: Remember to make `isPrime 2` true :)

Comment: @chi, oops. I hope it's fixed now!

Comment: The big question (I haven't tested) is whether full laziness will interfere with the inlining. If so, it might actually be necessary to switch to doing the recursion all by hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @dfeuer. I am familiar with the sieve of E algorithm but in this case I would like to stick to the current algorithm. I re-compiled the code with your recommendation (taking the 2 out and checking odd/even and with and without the inline bit), the execution time is exactly the same as my original code, both take 3.8 +/- 0.02 sec!

Comment: @bjpelcdev, I'm not home right now, so I can't really dig into it, but you might try taking the lists out manually. It's annoying, but should work reliably.

Comment: @bjpelcdev, I added another way.

Comment: @dfeuer, thanks very much again, making progress, your latest recommendation shaves off 1 whole second (almost 25%)! The reason I do not want to change the underlying algorithm is I am comparing different languages in a [blog post of mine](https://bjpelc.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/yet-another-language-speed-test-counting-primes-c-c-java-javascript-php-python-and-ruby-2/comment-page-1/#comment-4). I will add your latest version as an edit to my question.

Comment: You can speed this up some by making `isPrime` and `divisors` mutually recursive (`filter` the list in `divisors` by `isPrime`). On my computer, the first snippet is faster than the second if you do this.

Comment: @bjpelcdev few more things to try is, make a specialized `isOddPrimeAboveTwo` and thus loose few superfluous tests per number in your `primesNo`. Plus, make `primesNo` to count from 3 up in increments of 2; add an accumulating argument and mark it strict (with the bang), to make sure there are no thunks explosion, maybe inline the `isOddPrimeAboveTwo` into it.

Comment: @DavidYoung, that's a different algorithm; the question was about using this one.

Comment: Right, I wasn't thinking about that.

Comment: @WillNess, I think it's already strict enough; GHC can see that the accumulating parameter is tested on each iteration.

Comment: @dfeuer in OP's `primesNo`?

Comment: @WillNess I thought of that, but adding a strict accumulating parameter in `primesNo` didn't seem to improve the performance. That surprises me though.

Comment: @dfeuer, I have added your latest isPrime algorithm as an edit to the original post.

Comment: @DavidYoung that just means that GHC's strictness analyzer did good. :)

Comment: @WillNess, I didn't see what you were referring to. I suspect it matters little because the primality testing is much more expensive than the extra thunk per candidate.

Answer (score 3):

In general I've found that looping in Haskell is about 3-4 times slower than what can be accomplished with C.

To help understand the performance difference I slightly modified the
programs so that a fixed number of divisor tests are made per iteration
and added a parameter *e* to control how many iterations are made -
the number of (outer) iterations performed is 2^e. For each outer iteration
approx. 2^21 divisor tests are made.

The source code for each program and scripts to run and analyze the
results made be found here: https://github.com/erantapaa/loopbench

Pull-requests to improve the benchmarking are welcome.

Here are the results I get on a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo using ghc 7.8.3 (under OSX). The gcc used was "Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)".

```
e     ctime   htime  allocated  gc-bytes alloc/iter  h/c      dns
10   0.0101  0.0200      87424      3408             1.980   4.61
11   0.0151  0.0345     112000      3408             2.285   4.51
12   0.0263  0.0700     161152      3408             2.661   5.09
13   0.0472  0.1345     259456      3408             2.850   5.08
14   0.0819  0.2709     456200      3408             3.308   5.50
15   0.1575  0.5382     849416      9616             3.417   5.54
16   0.3112  1.0900    1635848     15960             3.503   5.66
17   0.6105  2.1682    3208848     15984             3.552   5.66
18   1.2167  4.3536    6354576     16032  24.24      3.578   5.70
19   2.4092  8.7336   12646032     16128  24.12      3.625   5.75
20   4.8332 17.4109   25229080     16320  24.06      3.602   5.72

e          = exponent parameter
ctime      = running time of the C program
htime      = running time of the Haskell program
allocated  = bytes allocated in the heap (Haskell program)
gc-bytes   = bytes copied during GC (Haskell program)
alloc/iter = bytes allocated in the heap / 2^e
h / c      = htime divided by ctime
dns        = (htime - ctime) divided by the number of divisor tests made
             in nanoseconds

# divisor tests made = 2^e * 2^11
```

Some observations:

1. The Haskell program performs heap allocation at a rate of about 24 bytes per (outer) loop iteration. The C program clearly does not perform any alloction and runs completely in L1 cache.
2. The gc-bytes count remains constant for e between 10 and 14 because no garbage collections were performed for those runs.
3. The time ratio h/c gets progressively worse as more allocations are made.
4. dps is a measure of the extra time the Haskell program takes per divisor test; it increases with the total amount of allocation made. Also there are some plateaus which suggest this is due to cache effects.

It is well known that GHC does not produce the same tight loop code that
a C compiler produces. The penalty you pay is approx. 4.6 ns per iteration.
Moreover, it looks like Haskell is also affected by cache effects due to
heap allocation.

24 bytes per allocation and 5 ns per loop iteration is not a lot for
most programs, but when you have 2^20 allocations and 2^40 loop iterations
it becomes a factor.

Comment: Allocation depends tremendously on the actual code. If you want Haskell code to perform really well, you have to pay attention to what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

*The C code uses 32-bit integers, while the Haskell code uses 64-bit integers.*

The original C code runs in **0.63** secs on my computer. However, if I replace the `int`-s with `long`-s, it runs in **2.07** seconds with gcc and **2.17** secs with clang.

In comparison, the updated `isPrime` function (see it in the thread question) runs in **2.09** seconds (with -O2 and -fllvm). Note that is slightly better than the clang-compiled C code, even though they use the same LLVM code generator.

The original Haskell code runs in **3.2** secs, which I think is an acceptable overhead for the convenience of using lists for iteration.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, this seems to have got to the bottom of it, I had completely overlooked the different int sizes. Comparing to the C code with long-s the speed difference is much more in line with what I was expecting.

Comment: I just tried importing Data.Int and converting the type declarations to Int32. This caused the running time to increase by approximately 10%.

Comment: That's only as expected if your native word size is 64 bits. In GHC the non-native sized integer operations are [implemented as foreign calls](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/GHC-Prim.html), while the native sized ops are primitives (translated to instructions eventually).

Comment: Thank you again, I'm certainly learning a lot from all the replies to my question.

Comment: @bjpelcdev, you might also want to try the list versions with GHC 7.10. There have been changes both to the libraries and the optimizer that may (possibly) make them work better.

Answer (score 1):

Inline everything, loose the superfluous tests, add strictness annotations just to be sure:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

-- pi(n) - the prime counting function, the number of prime numbers <= n
primesNo :: Int -> Int
primesNo n
    | n < 2 = 0
    | otherwise = g 3 1
 where
   g  k !cnt | k > n     = cnt
             | go 3      = g  (k+2) (cnt+1)
             | otherwise = g  (k+2) cnt
      where go f 
               | f*f > k   = True
               | otherwise = k `rem` f /= 0 && go (f+2) 

main = print $ primesNo (2^22)
```

The `go` testing function is as in dfeuer's answer. Compile with -O2 as usual, and *always test by running a standalone executable* (with something like `> test +RTS -s`).

Calls to `g` can be made direct (that's really micro-optimizing it):

```
primesNo n
    | n < 2 = 0
    | otherwise = g 3 1
 where
   g  k !cnt | k > n     = cnt
             | otherwise = go 3
      where go f 
               | f*f > k        = g (k+2) (cnt+1)
               | k `rem` f == 0 = g (k+2) cnt
               | otherwise      = go (f+2)
```

More substantial change (still keeping the algorithm arguably the same) which might or mightn't speed it up is to turn it inside out, to spare the squares computations: test by `[3]` all odds from 9 to 23, by `[3,5]` all odds from 25 to 47, etc., along the lines of [this segmented code](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Segmented_Generate_and_Test):

```
import Data.List (inits)

primesNo n = length (takeWhile (<= n) $ 2 : oddprimes)
  where
    oddprimes = sieve 3 9 [3,5..] (inits [3,5..]) 
    sieve x q ~(_:t) (fs:ft) =
      filter ((`all` fs) . ((/=0).) . rem) [x,x+2..q-2]
      ++ sieve (q+2) (head t^2) t ft
```

Sometimes tweaking your code into using `and` instead of `all` changes the speed too. Further speedup might be attempted by inlining and simplifying everything (replace `length` with counting etc.).

Comment: Thank you, Will. I have tried your first suggestion, that comes in at ~2.7 sec but only tests the odd numbers (I think?) so it doesn't actually speed up the algorithm, it just tests it against half the numbers. Could you please explain BangPatterns and !cnt? I haven't got that far with my Haskell yet as I only started last week.

Comment: Just tried out your solution with Data.Lists, interesting to note how much adding a type definition helps to increase the efficiency. As typed, without the type def (defaulting to Integers) it runs in 7.8secs, adding the type def Int->Int it runs in 4.5 sec.

Comment: yes, bang (!) patterns signify that the argument is evaluated strictly, i.e. right away, as opposed to the usual lazy delayed way. You can just try with or without it, to see whether there is any difference. The last code probably needs re-writing as loops (i.e. explicit recursion), but this too perhaps may be construed as algorithmic improvement. Ultimately, Haskell might be slower than C somewhat, but as long as *writing* correct code is much faster, it may be OK. "Real programmers code in Assembly" (TM). :)

Comment: I suspect a lot of that inlining is unnecessary. Loads of inlining happens in my version if I mark `isPrime` with an `INLINE` pragma. Looking at the core, it looks like your hand-inlined version is unboxed less completely than my version is. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Oh, that boxing is probably of no consequence. Forget that.